# How to change the Title text for a "Resource" component on right panel

Tags: admin-on-rest

This link explains the way to change the Text on Menu - https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/docs/Resource.md#options

But I would like to know how to change the Text which is rendered on right side panel i.e. when one clicks on the drawer menu. I see that if my code is like this :

`<Resource name="v2/posts" options={{ label: 'Posts' }} list={PostList} />`

> > then the Title is rendered as **V2/Posts List**. How do I give a custom title ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the `title` prop to your `PostList` component, e.g.

```
<PostList {...props} title={'Your title'} >
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could make your custom title:

```
<PostList title={<PostTitle />} {...props} >
```

where PostTitle is:

```
const PostTitle = ({ record }) => {
    return <span>My title</span>;
};
```